Generic component with default value for generic type
Lets say u have component with two inputs: object: T and propName: keyof T.
   @Component(...)
   class MyC<T> {
     @Input() object: T;
     @Input() propName: keyof T;
   }   

    <my-c [object]="{prop: 1}" [propName]="'prop'"></my-c> <!-- ok -->
    <my-c [object]="{prop: 1}" [propName]="'prop222'"></my-c> <!-- error -->

My goal is to provide default value for propName e.g. myProp, so desired result:
<my-c [object]="{propName: 1}"></my-c> <!-- ok -->
<my-c [object]="{otherPropName: 1}"></my-c> <!-- error -->
<my-c [object]="{otherPropName: 1}" [propName]="'otherPropName'"></my-c> <!-- ok-->

What I tried so far:

direct approach propName: keyof T = 'myProp' (results in compilation error in class itself)
changing MyC generic type (something like propName: T, object: {[key in T]: any}) (results in compilation error in class itself)

I hope there is a solution, or at least workaround.

A class of T with inputs of T KeyOf T .... Generic types called T Everywhere....
Can you share an example using the online builers to show us what you're really trying to do ?
